# Удалить элемент из vector и очистить память

Tags: c++

при очистки памяти через итератор возникает исключение.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector> 
#include "Shared.h"

using namespace std;

const int RangeItems = 3;

struct Anchor
{
    uint16_t anchor_addr;
    float range[RangeItems];
    float dbm;

    Anchor(uint16_t addr) : anchor_addr(addr), dbm(0) {}
};


struct Link
{
   vector<Anchor> Anchors;

   Link()
   {
       Anchors.reserve(10); //зарезервировать сразу N элементов
   }
};

struct Link* init_link(uint16_t addr)
{
    Link* l = new Link();
    Anchor* a = new Anchor(addr);
    l->Anchors.push_back(*a);
    return l;
}


void add_To_End(struct Link* p, uint16_t addr)
{
    Anchor* a = new Anchor(addr);
    p->Anchors.push_back(*a);
}


Result delete_Anchor(Link* p, uint16_t addr)
{
    for (auto it = p->Anchors.begin(); it != p->Anchors.end(); ++it)
    {
        Anchor a = *it;
        if (a.anchor_addr == addr)
        {
            p->Anchors.erase(it);
            delete &a;               //ECXEPTION!!!!!
            return Succsess;
        }
    }
    return NotFound;
}
```

Тестирую работу с вектором

```
int main()
{   
    uwb_data= init_link(1);
    add_To_End(uwb_data, 2);
    add_To_End(uwb_data, 3);
    add_To_End(uwb_data, 4);
    auto res = delete_Anchor(uwb_data, 3);
}
```

При удалении элемента из вектора, хочу очистить занимаемую элементом Anchor память, но возникает Исключение.

Comment: С помощью оператора `delete` следует удалять только объекты, с динамическим временем хранения созданные с помощью оператора `new`. На строке `delete &a;` удаляется объект с автоматическим временем хранения, созданный на три строки выше в этой же функции.

Comment: Зачем изобретать велосипед? Вектор STL может и в конец добавлять и удалять определённые элементы.

Comment: @bloody, причем тут  вектор? Распределитель вектора может освобождать память, которую выделял для элемента вектора, Получается, что элемент мы создали в одном участке памяти, а его вектор занес в другой.

Comment: Потеряна информация где был создан элемент изначала.  С таким кодом уже ничего не сделаешь _ утечка памяти неизбежна, и надежда только на уборщика мусора. Память освобождать нужно в самих функциях_ после push_back

Comment: Если я в vector храню указатели на структуры, которые я создал через new.  и потом хочу удалить элемент из вектора (указатель на структуру), то нужно ли мне очищать саму память занятую структурой? ведь из вектора просто пропадет указатель, а память не будет очищена. P.S. я переписал частично код и храню указатели vector<Anchor*> Anchors;

Comment: @Aldmi, с указателем получится, но лучше уж хранить умный указатель. Кроме того  вы не освобождаете память под  Link

Comment: под link и не надо, он живет всю жизнь программы. Про умные указатели почитаю, просто я на C# пишу, а тут надо сервер на контроллере ESP32 в общую инфраструктур добавить. Вот и вспоминаю институтский курс).

Comment: Мне важно динамически удалять и добавлять Anchor в коллекцию vector. при добавлении выделить память под Anchor , а при удалении очистить выделенную память

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вектор, как и все стандартные контейнеры, хранит *копии* того, что вы в него добавляете.

Т.е. вот здесь:

```
Anchor* a = new Anchor(addr);
p->Anchors.push_back(*a);
```

в вектор попадает копия объекта, т.е. `delete` на ней вызывать не надо, это надо делать на оригинале, на `a`. Вы этого не делаете, поэтому здесь утечка памяти.

В этом же причина краша - вы зовете `delete` не на том объекте, который создали в куче, а на его копии, которую создал вектор.

Вообще, в современном C++ почти никогда не нужно использовать `new` и `delete`, если только вы не делаете свой аналог вектора или чего-то подобного.

Правильно добавлять элемент так: `.emplace_back(addr);` или `.push_back(Anchor(addr));` (для вашего класса `.push_back(addr);` тоже сработает). При удалении `delete` не нужен, достаточно `erase`.

`Link` тоже нет смысла создавать через `new`. Просто `Link l; ... return l;`. И еще, раз вы пишете на С++ а не на С, то вместо `struct Link` достаточно писать просто `Link` (везде кроме самого определения структуры).

Comment: спасибо. а можно поподробнее в чем разница .push_back(Anchor(addr)); и создание через new?

Comment: @Aldmi Тут создается временный объект, копируюется (точнее перемещается) в вектор, потом автоматически удаляется. Если использовать `new`, то объект не временный, а в куче - его надо удалять руками, и плюс создание объектов в куче медленнее, чем не стеке. Есть еще третий вариант - `emplace_back`. По идее он лучше всего, потому что объект сразу создается в векторе, без каких-то дополниельных объектов.

Comment: а разве копирование структуры со стека в вектор не медленно? я поэтому и решил хранить указатели в векторе.

Comment: @Aldmi Вы не храните указатели в векторе, в храните в нем копии. Чтобы там были указатели, нужно написать `vector<Anchor *>`, а лучше `vector<unique_ptr<Anchor>>` Предполагаю, что выделение памяти в куче еще медленнее (плюс от копирования можно избавиться через `emplace_back`). Я бы на вашем месте не парился - когда начнет тормозить, тогда и будете думать.

Comment: Спасибо, за равернутый  ответ

Comment: @Aldmi,
 более подробный ответ  я намного раньше написал, а до того вам никто не lдавал правильную информацию.  Мне то все равно у кого какая предвзятость,, но вы сами  делаете все, чтобы больше вам не отвечали

Answer (score 0):

А получается вот что:

1. Вызов uwb_data=`init_link(1);` создает `Link` и  `Anchor` в
   свободной памяти с адресами соответственно `XL1` и`XA1`,   потом
   заносит  копию `Anchor` в вектор объекта  `Link`, который выделяет
   память `YA1` для этого объекта.

> То, что мы сохранили адрес `XL1` в `uwb_data`, вселяет надежду, что мы
> потом можем освобождать эту память(хотя вы этого не пытаетесь делать).

2. Дальше _ вызов  `add_To_End(uwb_data, 2);` создает `Anchor` с
   адресом `XA2` и заносит  копию `Anchor` в вектор (объекта  под
   `uwb_data`),  который выделяет
   память `YA2` для этого объекта.(в векторе уже два таких объекта)
3. Вызов:  `delete_Anchor(uwb_data, 1)` находит  в `uwb_data->Anchors`
   **два** схожих объекта и удаляет их. Таким образом вектор  освобождает память  `YA1` и `YA2`

> `delete &a;`   становится ошибкой, потому что `a` есть локальный
> объект. Но если вы пытаетесь каким то образом удалить объект вектора,
> то это тоже ошибка, потому что вектор уже его удалил.
>
> `А` упала, `В` пропала. Что осталось на трубе? А остались `XA1`, `XA2`
> и `XL1`. И, если,  последний хранится в  `uwb_data`, и после
> использования можно написать `delete uwb_data`, то информация о первых
> двух потеряна.

Есть много вариантов решения:

- не создавать `Anchor` в свободной памяти, а просто переместить  в
  вектор  `Anchors.emplace_back(Anchor(1))`(наверное так лучше)
- или после   `push_back(*a)` освобождать память под `а` (ведь объект
  все равно уже не нужен, так как в векторе его копия)
- Использовать умные указатели
- или(плохой вариант) где то хранить  указатели на  объекты, созданных в динамической
  области нами(не распределителем вектора). Но нужно ли это?...

Comment: Тут не важно , что память для 10 объектов зарезервирована конструктором Link, и при добавлении не выделяется память, а просто конструируется объект в заранее выделенной памяти.